# T-SQL Replace HTML tags except for P tags

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I have this function that is well documented on the internet to strip out HTML in a SQL query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnStripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @Start INT
     DECLARE @End INT
     DECLARE @Length INT

 SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
 SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
 SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1

 WHILE @Start > 0
    AND @End > 0
    AND @Length > 0
 BEGIN
     SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
     SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
     SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
     SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
 END
     RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
 END
GO
```

I need to amend this function to strip out all HTML apart from opening and closing p tags `<p></p>`.

Is anyone able to help as I've been at it for a while and haven't yet had a breakthrough.

Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: Why are you doing this in the *database*? Parsing and replacing HTML tags is **hard** because it's typically malformed. You can't even use regular expressions to do what you ask, much less simple pattern substitutions

Comment: A far, far better idea would be to clean up the HTML on the *client* side, using a sanitizer library, regular expressions, XML transformations or HTML parsing libraries like HTML Agility.

Comment: In total agreement with @PanagiotisKanavos here; simply build a little console/web app in some language of your choice to sanitize it for you if you cannot do elsewhere. Better tools for text replacement and debug and logging.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, even in SQL. As mentioned in comments, **the** best way is to not try to do this in SQL, but in a tool suited for HTML parsing. Anyway, you could try this:

You could start with

```
SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(REPLACE(@HTMLText, '<P>', 'DONOTDELETEOPENINGTAG'), '<\p>', 'DONOTDELETECLOSINGTAG'))
```

Do the rest of your removals, and end with:

```
SET @HTMLText = REPLACE(REPLACE(@HTMLText, 'DONOTDELETEOPENINGTAG', '<P>'), 'DONOTDELETECLOSINGTAG', '<\p>'))
```

Of course you have to make sure the values `'DONOTDELETEOPENINGTAG'` and `'DONOTDELETECLOSINGTAG'` do not appear in the rest of the string. It seems unlikely they would, but you never know...

Comment: Thanks @honeybadger. I had done this but I was hoping to use a function so that it could be reused easily.

Comment: You could always put it in a function if you like.

Comment: The "better way" is to not do this with T-SQL in the first place. HTML is notoriously hard to parse by itself, much less handle the incomplete HTML created by programs and users

Comment: Thanks @honeybadger, I've done your suggestion and used the replace and put into a function. It seems to work ok. I agree its not the best way of doing it but the only one I can do in this instance.

Comment: @user3455191...Glad I could be of help. You can accept the answer if you like.